# In what way can the image of bowels "packed in furnace" recall an image of a sea "tumbling in harness"?

Tags: poetry, intertextuality, ted-hughes, dylan-thomas

I'm trying to get a grasp of a poetical image of being "packed in furnace", found in Ted Hughes' Crow's opening poem ["Two Legends"](https://genius.com/18633438):

> Two Legends
>
> I
>
> Black was the without eye
> Black the within tongue
> Black was the heart
> [...]
> Black the blood in its loud tunnel
> Black the bowels **packed in furnace**
> [...]

During my Googling, I came across [this work](http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/1483/1/1483.pdf?DDD11+EThOS%20(BL)), which suggests:

> 'packed in furnace' recalls Thomas' sea, 'tumbling in harness'.

This quote is from Dylan Thomas' ["A Refusal to Mourn the Death, by Fire, of a Child in London"](https://poets.org/poem/refusal-mourn-death-fire-child-london):

> Never until the mankind making
> Bird beast and flower
> Fathering and all humbling darkness
> Tells with silence the last light breaking
> And the still hour
> Is come of the sea **tumbling in harness**

I have no idea in what way does the "packed in furnace" image can recall the "tumbling in harness" image.
Can this analogy make sense in some way?

Answer (score 2):

One of the meanings of “furnace” is:

> **furnace, *n.* 3.** A closed fireplace for heating a building by means of hot-air or hot-water pipes
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

(This apparatus is more commonly known as a “boiler”.)

So Hughes’ image is of intestines being packed in the abdomen like hot water pipes in a boiler.

I think the most plausible way to make sense of “tumbling in harness” is to use this sense:

> **harness, *n.*, 4.a.** The trappings or accoutrements of a horse
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

and take Thomas’s image to be the waves of the sea breaking on the shore like “white horses” in harness.

Why Owen Johnson thought that the one phrase recalled the other in his 1991 Ph.D. thesis, I do not know. Perhaps it is just that both are three-word participial phrases with “in” as the second word, like Shakespeare’s “flourishing in arms”. The comparison with Thomas appears in the middle of a list of “echoes” of other poets that Johnson found in Hughes, and not all of these echoes are particularly convincing, so perhaps he had simply come to the bottom of his barrel.

Comment: Another similarity is that "furnace" and "harness" pretty much rhyme with each other.

Comment: Both also convey a similar metaphor, of a chaotic mass tightly constrained.